# Batch Class Error as System.StringException: Invalid id at mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Owner.Email)

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

I have a written a Batch Class to send an notification email 60 days before the contract end date.I have created the email template and used in the code.But the system throws an error as :

> Batch Class Error as System.StringException: Invalid id at line #29 
>   mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Owner.Email);

Batch Class :

```
global class SixtyDaysNotificationEmail implements Database.Batchable < sObject >, Schedulable, Database.Stateful {
    global List<String> errorMessages = new List<String>();
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        Date ed = Date.today().addDays(60);
        System.debug(Date.today().addDays(60));

        set<Id> setContractIds = new set<Id>();

        for(Contract_role__c objContract: [SELECT  Contract__c FROM Contract_role__c WHERE Role__c = 'Subscription Administrator' AND Contract__r.EndDate =: ed]) {
            setContractIds.add(objContract.Contract__c);
        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select  id, Contract_Name__c , EndDate ,Contact_Email__c, Contract_End_Date_2__c,  Account.Owner.Email ,Account.Owner.Manager.Email,Owner.Email FROM Contract  WHERE Id IN: setContractIds');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Contract > recs) {
        List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mailList = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
        for (Contract c: recs) {
            if (c.Contact_Email__c != null) {
                List < String > toAddresses = new List < String > ();
                List < String > CcAddresses = new List < String > ();
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                toAddresses.add(c.Contact_Email__c);
                ccAddresses.add(c.Account.Owner.Email);
               // toAddresses.add(c.Account.Owner.Manager.Email);
                mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                mail.setCcAddresses(CcAddresses);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Owner.Email);
                mail.setTemplateId('00X4B000000M3zx');
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
               // mail.setSubject('Notification Before 100 Days of Contract End Date to Account Executive and Manager');
               // String messageBody = '<html><body>Hi ,The Contract Named ' + c.Contract_Name__c  + ',<br>Will get Expired within 60 Days . <br>Kindly take approriate action to inform the Customer.<br><br><b>Regards,</b><br>CAB</body></html>';
               // mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody);
                mailList.add(mail);
            }
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        AsyncApexJob aaj = [Select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, MethodName, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email from AsyncApexJob where Id =:BC.getJobId()];

        // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {aaj.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('JOB Salesforce NotificationEmailtoAccountExecutive Finished: ' + aaj.Status);
        String bodyText='Total Job Items ' + aaj.TotalJobItems + ' Number of records processed ' + aaj.JobItemsProcessed + ' with '+ aaj.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.\n';
        bodyText += 'Number of Error Messages ' + errorMessages.size() + '\n';
        bodyText += 'Error Message' + String.join(errorMessages, '\n');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        NotificationEmailtoAccountExecutive batchable = new NotificationEmailtoAccountExecutive();
        database.executebatch(batchable);
    }
}
```

The targetobjectid should be for the contact.But when i use mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Contact_Email__c); the system throws the same error .
Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Owner.Email);` will set the `Email` field to `setTargetObjectId` but that method expects an `Id` field of `Contact`, `Lead` or `User`.

So if your intention is to send the mail to owner of Contract (`c.Owner.Email`), then use `mail.setTargetObjectId(c.OwnerId);`

If your intention is to send the mail to the contact who signed the Contract, then use `mail.setTargetObjectId(c.CustomerSignedId);` where `CustomerSignedId` is the Contact who signed the Contract.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Maha:Thanks for your response.I have Custom object as Contact which has loop up relation with contract.If i use mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Contact__cId) , the system throws an error.Invalid field Contact__cId for SObject Contract.When i use mail.setTargetObjectId(c.CustomerSignedId) ,the system throws an error as REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template.Any suggestion.

Comment: Your custom object name is Contact? what's the API name? Contact__c. You can't user custom object record id in setTargetObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

SetTargetObjectId() method will accept only ID of the contact, lead, or user.

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Contact_c) //Specify related Contact Id
```